# Get session ID of spawned session using Expect in Perl

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I'm using `Expect` to ssh. I want to know the Session ID of the spawned session. How do I do that?

This is my code:

```
my $addr = "10.101.10.102";
my $cmd = "ssh username@".$addr;
my $exp = Expect->spawn($cmd) or die "Cannot spawn command\n";
```

Comment: Are you talking about the session that contains process groups, as explained [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html)? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `$exp->pid()` method of Expect. the documentation for the Expect module says:

```
$object->pid()
Return pid of $object, if one exists. Initialized filehandles will not have pids (of course).
```

I have tried this in a simple test to telnet to local host, and do a unix ps command to see the processes and also the `$exp->pid()` command and they match.

```
use strict;
use Expect;
my $exp = Expect->spawn("ssh localhost") or die "cannot spawn command\n";
print `ps -ef | grep -i "ssh localhost\$"` ;
print "PID of spawned process is: ", $exp->pid(), "\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
providnt  4389  4302  0 09:42 pts/1    00:00:00 ssh localhost
PID of spawned process is: 4389
```